# Does it matter the region on psn?

Tags: psn

I live in spain but I want to play online in English.
When I put my region in Spain it only lets me put spanish as my language.
So can I change the region to somewhere with English or would there be a problem?

Comment: If you want to play games in English, you should probably ask about that.

Comment: Regions for PSN, same for XBOX, are taken very serious and messing around to much can cause issues preventing you from purchasing games all together. Not all games are legally allowed to be played in all regions and some countries do not have legislation in place for digital content, hence a lot of games are "not available" in some countries through PSN or XBOX store. Even their gold membership games are restricted. I don't remember the links but literally google for `how to change region on psn` to get the instruction on their website.

Comment: Just to elaborate on that. I had region issues because I had to create a Microsoft Account for UK, even though I live in Ireland as back then Microsoft didn't think UK and Ireland should have separate regions online. However, when I purchased an XBOX the XBOX was set to Ireland.  I was never able to purchase a single game as the regions were messed up between the console and the website. Even talking to support could not fix it and changing region on xbox did not help either. It made it worse as my xbox was then set to UK forcing the website to switch region every time I logged in.

Comment: @Fran Please don't answer in comments.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I'm not answering in comments as I don't know what OPs issue is, as I don't have reference data backing up any facts I'm only sharing information based on personal experience which is **not** a valid answer. Answer should be based on facts, preferably with links to references in this case. I'm well aware how to use Stackexchange sites :)

Comment: Comments are not for sharing information, that's what an answer is.

Comment: @Fran Personal experience is accepted for answers, as long as your experience is described in the answer.

Comment: I don't see a reason to change the region when it's perfectly possible to just change the language to English.

Answer (score 1):

Although the system is Spanish, which is - I guess - a normal thing for a guy living in Spain, my rough guess is that games usually allow you to modify the setting for the game content language. If the issue comes from the game supporting only Spanish, then I think it's time to buy a more "Europe-oriented" game ?
I live in Middle East, and I prefer buying Europe-supporting games because of their support of French (and because it's WAY cheaper but shhh).